# Overwriting Writer Issue

Tags: c#, list, streamwriter

I'm writing a list to a file, the list gets data from the form app from text I type in. This works but it overwrites the file every time I start the form instead of saving it and adding new data. How Can I add "AppendAllLines" or "WriteAllLines" to this as a solution?

```
     public List<String> listDeliveries()
    {
        List<String> listDeliveries = new List<string>();           
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Database.txt"))
        {
            foreach (Delivery del in deliveries)
            {
                String delAsString = del.summary();                   

                listDeliveries.Add(delAsString);

                writer.WriteLine(delAsString);                   
            }

        }
        return listDeliveries;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ToList` to create your list and `File.AppendAllLines` to append the lines from the list:

```
List<string> listDeliveries = deliveries.Select(d => d.summary())
                                        .ToList();
File.AppendAllLines("Database.txt", listDeliveries);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var listDeliveries = deliveries.Select(d=>d.summary()).ToList();
File.AppendAllLines("Database.txt", listDeliveries);
return listDeliveries;
```

Comment: You'd *then* end up going through it again in order to create `listDeliveries`. Why?

Comment: well, it is obviously that it should be stored if list is needed, but that was not a question

Comment: Well the question is couched in terms of a method which is already building up the list to return, so I think it's reasonable to assume that still needs to be part of the solution. If the *only* thing you change is how it's written to disk, as per your solution, then that misses out on the commonality.

Comment: This Works, however it seems to store the first line in the list twice every time I open/close the app?

Comment: why you think it stores twice? what you mean?

Comment: Well, it stores what ever I type in for what's to be in the list. But it stores the first line of what I type in twice

Answer (score 1):

> How Can I add "AppendAllLines" or "WriteAllLines" to this as a solution?

Well it looks like you just want:

```
List<String> listDeliveries = deliveries.Select(x => x.summary()).ToList();
File.AppendAllLines("Database.txt", listDeliveries);
return listDeliveries;
```

(Yes, you *can* create the `StreamWriter` with `true` as the second argument, but `AppendAllLines` is simpler...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Database.txt", true))
```

To append rather than overwrite

Answer (score 0):

Use overloaded constructor that allows you to specify whether to append or not. The default is `false`

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Database.txt", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the StreamWriter, pass in a boolean that will tell it to append data to the file instead of overwrite.

```
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Database.txt", true))
```